# jQuery.attr() guarantee lowercase?

Tags: jquery, attributes

Does `$(selector).attr(name)` guarantee that the result is lowercase if the attribute is found?

Comment: Can u take guarantee that user will not disable javascript..:-P

Answer (score 3):

It will return the value in whatever case it was set.

```
<div class="sOmEcLaSs">content</div>
```

.

```
alert( $('div').attr('class')​​​​ );​​​​  // will alert sOmEcLaSs
```

If you want to convert to lowercase, you can use `.toLowerCase()`.

```
alert( $('div').attr('class').toLowerCase() );​​​​  // will alert someclass
```

---

Code for jQuery's `attr` return statements (not Sizzle):

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/attributes.js#L308

or

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/attributes.js#L325

Answer (score 2):

No because .attr calls the javascript .getAttribute method without any parameters. 
As you can see in the code bellow.

getAttribute defaults to 0 which is a case-insensitive so it returns exactly what it finds.

```
     ATTR: function(elem, match){
            var name = match[1],
                result = Expr.attrHandle[ name ] ?
                    Expr.attrHandle[ name ]( elem ) :
                    elem[ name ] != null ?
                        elem[ name ] :
                        elem.getAttribute( name ),
                value = result + "",
                type = match[2],
                check = match[4];

            return result == null ?
                type === "!=" :
                type === "=" ?
                value === check :
                type === "*=" ?
                value.indexOf(check) >= 0 :
                type === "~=" ?
                (" " + value + " ").indexOf(check) >= 0 :
                !check ?
                value && result !== false :
                type === "!=" ?
                value !== check :
                type === "^=" ?
                value.indexOf(check) === 0 :
                type === "$=" ?
                value.substr(value.length - check.length) === check :
                type === "|=" ?
                value === check || value.substr(0, check.length + 1) === check + "-" :
                false;
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can't rely on case-sensitive attribute searches and still be cross-browser browser compatible. In the older IE DOM, I recall that all tags and attributes are stored and returned in upper case; so the tag `<div id="mydiv">` gets rendered internally as `<DIV ID=mydiv>`. So in Netscape or Firefox, the attribute name would be `id` and in IE it would be `ID`. But even with dynamically created elements, which are stored with the desired case, there are inconsistencies just within IE. For example, IE6 and IE8 behave completely differently with `getAttribute()`. Compare:

```
<div></div>

var myDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
myDiv.setAttribute('id','id1');
myDiv.setAttribute('ID','id2');
console.log(x.getAttribute('ID')); // IE6, return "id1", IE8, returns "id2"
console.log(x.getAttribute('ID',true)); // IE6, return "id2", returns "id2"
```